# How to select rows that contain a certain phrase using SQL in R

Tags: sql, r

I am using SQL in R for some data.
I need to select the indicators that contain 'Life expectancy' using the code dbGetQuery

````
```
dbGetQuery(wdidb, 'SELECT Indicator_name
                   FROM Indicators
                   WHERE Indicator_name = "life expectancy"')
```
````

I have tried the above code but that only selects the indicator_name that are Life Expectancy not that contain 'life expectancy'

Does anyone know how I can alter the code

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `LIKE` expression:

```r
dbGetQuery(wdidb, "SELECT Indicator_name
                   FROM Indicators
                   WHERE Indicator_name LIKE '%life expectancy%'")
```

To do this check regardless of the case of the indicator name, use `LOWER()` on the LHS:

```r
dbGetQuery(wdidb, "SELECT Indicator_name
                   FROM Indicators
                   WHERE LOWER(Indicator_name) LIKE '%life expectancy%'")
```

Comment: Isn't `like` typically case-insensitive? `select 1 where 'A' like '%a%'` works. Perhaps this comment should be: on which DBMS is `like` _not_ case-insensitive?

Comment: @r2evans I'm pretty sure that on certain databases with a case sensitive collation, `LIKE` would also be case sensitive.

Comment: I think I need to better understand "collation" and how it isdefined/controlled within DBMS environments. (I've tested on SQL Server, Postgres, and SQLite, all linux environments, and they all are case-insensitive, so I clearly need to keep reading.) Thanks!

Comment: `LIKE` is just an operator, like `=`.  Its behavior really depends on the underlying column.  I wager that all your tests are on case insensitive columns.

Comment: TIL that a _column_ (not just a comparison) can be defined as case-insensitive ... and here I thought I knew something about databases. Thanks again!